# Kernel Crash and Restarting during reading OPC data using OpenOPC

Tags: python, kernel, restart, opc

I got stuck up with small issue while using openOPC.
I have installed python 3.8.3 on windows 10 64 bit system.
Installed OpenOPC-Python3x through pip install.
Running Matrikon OPC simulation server and OPC explorer for data simulation.

While running the following code, I'm able to connect with Matrikon OPC server, but when I try to read/write the data, kernel is restarting and I'm not able to get any data.

```
`import OpenOPC
opc = OpenOPC.client()
print(opc.servers())
opc.connect('Matrikon.OPC.Simulation.1')
print(opc['Random.Real8'])   
opc.close()`
```

I also tried with different IDEs (Jupyter, Spyder, IDLE), but same result.

When I try to read the same data through anaconda command prompt, data is coming without any problem.

Kindly help me to get out of this issue.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q98Lw.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I have seen the same thing. The only solution I found was replacing the 64 bit python version with a 32 bit python version.